# Returning early from a Powershell loop in a function

Tags: powershell, syntax

I'm trying to make a simple "coalesce" function but struggling with Powershell return syntax

Attempts:

```bsh
function coalesce {
   foreach($item in $args) {
     if ($item) {
       return $item
       break # also tried continue and exit
     }
   }
 }
coalesce($nil,2,3)
2
3
```

```bsh
function coalesce {
   ForEach-Object -InputObject $args { If($_) { return $_; exit } } # also tried continue and break
}
coalesce($nil,2,3)

2
3
```

So how do I simulate a `return` inside a loop that exits the function in any other programming language?

Comment: what do you expect from that code? when i run it without the `break`, it returns the whole array as expected. you DO realize that by calling it with parens and commas you have made the input into ONE array, not 3 items? [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

in powershell, if you call a function with parens wrapped around comma delimited items, you get ONE OBJECT. [*grin*] your function is working and returning the array of three objects. the *proper* way to call that function with three inputs is thus ...

```
coalesce $Null 2 3
```

please also note that `$nil` is not `$Null` ... it's a new variable named `nil` with nothing in it - in other words, with the value of `$Null` in it.